# Angular resolve with nested API Calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

The procedure of below code is to fetch email id from an api and resolve with details of that email id. I am in need to return the details directly as a response instead of needing to subscribe since I have just have this.route.snapshot.data.value assigned to a component and it takes data rightaway. Is there a way to achieve it? Please favour.  I haven't written nested ones previously in resolve so , please guide. I just gave a try as below but it doesn't satisfy the need.

```
  resolve() {


        let info = environment.DETAIL_URL;

        return this.appService.getInfo(info).pipe(map((res) => {
            let user: any = res;
            console.log(res);
            let params: any = {};
            params.personID = user.emailID;
            return this.appService.getDataFromParams(environment.DATA_URL, params).pipe(map((res) => {
                return res;
            }))
        }))
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `.pipe(map((res) => { return res; }))`? It does absolutely nothing.

Comment: originally i do a modification on the response object and return.

Answer (score 1):

Use `switchMap()` instead of `map()`.

```
return this.appService.getInfo(info).pipe(
    switchMap(user =>
        this.appService.getDataFromParams(environment.DATA_URL, {
            personID: user.emailID
        })
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mergeMap` or `switchMap` instead of `map` to return data from the inner observable. there's also `exhaustMap` and `concatMap`, in case you want to know them all - they all have different behavior

```
  resolve() {


        let info = environment.DETAIL_URL;

        return this.appService.getInfo(info).pipe(mergeMap((res) => {
            let user: any = res;
            console.log(res);
            let params: any = {};
            params.personID = user.emailID;
            return this.appService.getDataFromParams(environment.DATA_URL, params).pipe(map((res) => {
                return res;
            }))
        }))
    }
```

Comment: I actually tried this. for some reason, getInfo gives response in console but getDatafromparams didn't even happen. getDatafromparams  internally runs  a query and i don't see it hit in console. and response of route.snapshot.data.user be a blank array [ ] .

Comment: it is supposed to work. if it doesn't, the problem is elsewhere. please share more code. maybe there's something wrong with `getDataFromParams`? does it receive proper arguments? add some logging to check or debug

Comment: I did a silly mistake hitting a wrong url . and yea, using mergeMap on top works. Thanks for that. Just asking, how'll the same work if 3 API calls are involved like API 1 gives result 1 which is used in API 2 to give result 2 which is inturn used in API 3 and the third API result alone need to be resulted?

Comment: it works the same:
`api1.pipe(
switchMap(res1 => api2(res1)),
switchMap(res2 => api3(res2)),
).subscribe(res3 => do your stuff)`